# how can I know the iOS app that I made is 32 bit or not? and how can I change that?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, 32bit-64bit, iphone-64bit

as you know after WWDC all of the apple Developer has lots of problems because we have to submit 64 bit application - I am using swift 3 and Xcode 8.3.2 But my app version is iOS 9.3 and I can test this application on iphone4s so how can I change this app to 64 bit and another question 
I have iPhone 4s so this application that I am building will not have permission to run in my iPhone ? and should I sell this phone or I can download 32 bit app in this phone after 2018 ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change to 64 bit you should:

1. Select your project
2. Select your target
3. Select Build Settings
4. Look for Valid Architectures
5. Set only arm64 as the Valid Architecture

Comment: its arm64 armv7 armv7s and Remember that I want to launch 32 bit too because the iOS is 9.3 and I want this application launch on the iPhone 4s and above

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Is there any update regarding this?

Comment: if you mean any changes until I asked this question I don't think so